# Insertar array de artículos vendidos de acuerdo al array generado de INSERT id en php

Tags: php, array, while, insert, foreach

Este fragmento de código forma parte de una API en CodeIgniter llamada desde una app, la parte de la llamada desde la APP es un array `(DATA)`  por POST que puede contener n cantidad de arrays de productos pero siempre con la misma cantidad de elementos:
`data:[ {"product_id":"10","qty":"1","store_id":"5","unit_value":"1","unit":"PZA","price":"50","rewards":"0"}, {"product_id":"11","qty":"1","store_id":"6","unit_value":"1","unit":"PZA","price":"50","rewards":"0"} ]`

y la recepción se compone de dos tablas `(SALE) y (SALE_ITEMS)`, (TESTIDS Solo de pruebas)
donde se guardan por un lado la venta global en `(SALE)"BLOQUE 01"` por cada `STORE_ID`

Tabla SALE

```
      CREATE TABLE `sale` (
      `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `on_date` date NOT NULL,
      `delivery_time_from` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `delivery_time_to` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `note` longtext NOT NULL,
      `is_paid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `total_amount` double NOT NULL,
      `total_rewards` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `total_kg` double NOT NULL,
      `total_items` double NOT NULL,
      `socity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `delivery_address` longtext NOT NULL,
      `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `delivery_charge` double NOT NULL,
      `new_store_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `assign_to` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `asign_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `payment_method` varchar(200) NOT NULL
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Tabla SALE_ITEMS

```
       CREATE TABLE `sale_items` (
       `sale_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `product_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
       `qty` double NOT NULL,
       `unit` enum('gram','kg','nos') NOT NULL,
       `unit_value` double NOT NULL,
       `price` double NOT NULL,
       `qty_in_kg` double NOT NULL,
       `rewards` varchar(200) NOT NULL
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Es decir si el array contiene 2 subarrays(artículos) como en el ejemplo de (DATA) correspondientes
a 2 `STORE_ID` diferentes, solo se guardan 2 `SALE_ID`,
y se obtiene el arreglo de 2 `ID` (array) uno por cada INSERT, hasta aquí todo bien.

y por otro lado
se insertan los artículos de la venta correspondiente de acuerdo al ID del INSERT devuelto de `(SALE)` en
`(SALE_ITEMS)` tantos productos `PRODUCT_ID` como existan en el array por cada `STORE_ID` y correspondiente a cada `SALE_ID`

funciona parcialmente ya que los `BLOQUES 01 y 02` funcionan bien pero el `BLOQUE 03` duplica los artículos tantas veces como existan SALE_ID distintos es decir si el array principal contiene 2 artículos (sub-arrays)
y si los 2 pertenecen a 2 `STORE_ID` diferentes, 1 articulo a un `STORE_ID` o bien `SALE_ID` y otros articulo a otro `STORE_ID` o bien `SALE_ID`  se insertan 4 artículos ,2 veces cada articulo esto es LOGIGO por el `FOREACH 03` pero no he sabido como resolver y EVITAR que se duplique
y que se inserte solo el numero exacto de artículos por cada `SALE_ID` o bien `STORE_ID` que sería para el caso de este ejemplo de (DATA) un `SALE_ID` en SALE y un SALE_ITEMS respectivamente para cada `PRODUCT_ID`, **al final la idea es poder insertar el numero de artículos correspondientes real a cada venta** que para este este ejemplo serían 2 artículos y poder traer de vuelta para otro proceso los artículos correspondientes
de cada SALE_ID y por cada STORE_ID respectivamente, es decir STORE_ID => SALE_ID => Artículos, llamando solo a SALE_ITEMS con el ID correspondiente de SALE_ID en SALE

```
    /* INICIA Bloque 01 - Este bloque funciona bien*/            
      $data_post = $this->input->post("data");  
                
      $data_array = json_decode($data_post);
      $ids = array(); 
  foreach ($data_array as $bysale) {  
       $payment_method= $this->input->post("payment_method");
                
       $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post("date")));
                
                
         $times = explode('-',$this->input->post("time"));
         $fromtime = date("h:i a",strtotime(trim($times[0]))) ;
         $totime = date("h:i a",strtotime(trim($times[1])));
         $user_id = $this->input->post("user_id");
$insert_array = array("user_id"=>$user_id,
                      "on_date"=>$date,
                      "delivery_time_from"=>$fromtime,
                      "delivery_time_to"=>$totime,
                      "delivery_address"=>$location->house_no,
                      "socity_id" => $location->socity_id, 
                      "delivery_charge" => $location->delivery_charge,
                      "location_id" => $location->location_id, 
                      "payment_method" => $payment_method,
                       "new_store_id" => $bysale->store_id
                                      );
                
       $ids[] = array('sale_id' => $id = $this->common_model->data_insert("sale",$insert_array), 'store_id' => $bysale->store_id);
            } 
   /* TERMINA bloque 01 - Funcionando bien */ 
   
   /* Inicializar variables de bloque 02 */
   
                $total_rewards = 0;
                $total_price = 0;
                $total_kg = 0;
                $total_items = array();
   
   /* Termina inicializar variables de bloque 02 y Bloque 04*/
   
   /* INICIA bloque 02 - Insertar productos correspondientes a cada SALE_ID */
                foreach ($ids as $idr){ //INICIA FOREACH 02
                
    /* Bloque de comprobación de IDS */
                $insert_ids = array("sale_id"=>$idr['sale_id'], "store_id" => $idr['store_id']);
                $this->common_model->data_insert("testids",$insert_ids);
    /* Termina bloque de comprobación de IDS CORRECTAMENTE*/
                
                
    /* Inicia bloque 03 INSERT de productos */            
    foreach($data_array as $dt){ 
                    
               
           $qty_in_kg = $dt->qty; 
         if($dt->unit=="gram"){
           $qty_in_kg =  ($dt->qty * $dt->unit_value) / 1000;     
                               }
                    
   $total_rewards = $total_rewards + ($dt->qty * $dt->rewards);
   $total_price = $total_price + ($dt->qty * $dt->price);
   $total_kg = $total_kg + $qty_in_kg;
   $total_items[$dt->product_id] = $dt->product_id;    
                    
   $array = array("product_id"=>$dt->product_id,
                    "qty"=>$dt->qty,
                    "unit"=>$dt->unit,
                    "unit_value"=>$dt->unit_value,
                    "sale_id"=>$idr['sale_id'],
                    "price"=>$dt->price,
                    "qty_in_kg"=>$qty_in_kg,
                    "rewards" =>$dt->rewards
                    );
         $this->common_model->data_insert("sale_items",$array);
                    
                    
            }  //TERMINA FOREACH 03
   /* TERMINA bloque 03 INSERT de productos TERMINA INCORRECTAMENTE (DUPLICA LOS REGISTROS)*/        
                
   
                 } // TERMINA FOREACH 02
   /* TERMINA bloque 02 */
```

He intentado reemplazar el `FOREACH` por un `WHILE` pero no se como desarrollar correctamente el procedimiento he leído algo sobre ambas funciones inlcuyendo `FOR` también probe haciendo una función separada de esta y llamándola para hacer el registro de productos pero igual se duplica, definitivamente me supero este problema que seguramente es fácil de resolver teniendo la experiencia, agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda

Comment: He formateado un poco el código para que sea más legible

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, después de seguir leyendo y buscando opciones para lograrlo lo hice de la siguiente forma, no se si el rendimiento sea el optimo o si la forma de realizarlo sea la correcta pero funciona tal y como lo quería.

primero agregue la opción `TRUE`

```
   $data_array = json_decode($data_post, true);
```

Después ordene y reagrupe el array por `STORE_ID` con esta función

```
    function orderArray($array,$groupkey){
    if (count($array)>0)
    {
    $keys = array_keys($array[0]);
    $removekey = array_search($groupkey, $keys);        if 
   ($removekey===false)
    return array("Clave \"$groupkey\" no existe");
    else
    unset($keys[$removekey]);
    $groupcriteria = array();
    $return=array();
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
    $item=null;
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        $item[$key] = $value[$key];
    }
    $busca = array_search($value[$groupkey], $groupcriteria);
    if ($busca === false)
    {
        $groupcriteria[]=$value[$groupkey];
        $return[]=array($groupkey=>$value[$groupkey],'productos'=>array());
        $busca=count($return)-1;
    }
    $return[$busca]['productos'][]=$item;
    }
    return $return;
     }
     else
    return array();
     }
```

Esta función es sólo para identificar que x numero de productos pertenecen a una sola tienda y poder agruparlos todos en la misma venta si se vendieron todos en el mismo único acto y poder generar los IDS correspondientes a cada venta `SALE_ID`

Luego en el `FOREACH 01` agrega una llamada a otra función para filtrar los productos del `STORE_ID`que se esta recorriendo en ese instante

```
     $productos = $this->product_model->search_product($data_array, $bysale['store_id']);
```

con esta función

```
      function search_product( $products, $name ) {
       $matching_items = array_values( array_filter(
       $products,
      function( $product ) use ( $name ) {
      return $product['store_id'] === $name;
       }
       ) );
      return $matching_items;

       }
```

Después agregue el nuevo array de productos de ese `STORE_ID` o `SALE_ID` al array existente

```
     $ids[] = array('sale_id' => $id = $this->common_model->data_insert("sale",$insert_array), 'store_id' => $bysale['store_id'], 'productos' => $productos);
```

y por ultimo en le `FOREACH 03` cambie

```
  foreach($idr['productos'] as $dt){ //INICIA FOREACH 03
```

y listo, ahora guarda correctamente los productos correspondientes a la venta por `SALE_ID` y por `STORE_ID` por ejemplo :

Si el usuario compro en el mismo acto 2 artículos distintos a una tienda, mas uno  a otra tienda y otro mas a otra tienda, son en total 4 artículos 2 de los cuales pertenecen a una misma tienda y los otros 2 artículos a otras dos tiendas distintas cada una entre si, que son en REALIDAD 3 ventas (· 3 distintos `SALE_ID` ) distintas con su respectivo numero de artículos cada una, al final lo que logre es algo parecido a la APP china WISH, que puedes comprar en diversas tiendas en un solo pedido o en un solo acto y a cada tienda se le asigna su respectivo `SALE_ID` del usuario, ahora el reto es hacer que un sólo repartidor puede atender todo el pedido de ese usuario, esa venta o esos 3 `SALE_ID`